# Can't pass controlled component values to redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I created a Date of Birth component which is supposed to have separate fields for Date, Month and Year. The component will combine the values and provide a date string in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Code for `Date of birth` component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Col, Input } from 'antd';

const InputGroup = Input.Group;

class DateOfBirthInput extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value:{}
    };
    console.log(props);
  }

  public handleChange = (event: any) => {
    const date:any = _.get(this.state,"value");
    if(event.target.id === 'day'){
      date.day = event.target.value;
    }
    if(event.target.id === 'month'){
      date.month = event.target.value;
    }
    if(event.target.id === 'year'){
      date.year = event.target.value;
    }
    this.setState({
      value: date
    });
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="ant-form-item-label"><label title="Date of birth">Date of birth</label></div>
        <InputGroup>
          <Col span={4}>
            <Input
              placeholder="MM"
              id="month"
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </Col>
          <Col span={1}/>
          <Col span={4}>
            <Input
              placeholder="DD"
              id="day"
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </Col>
          <Col span={1}/>
          <Col span={5}>
            <Input
              placeholder="YYYY"
              id="year"
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <h4>Date of birth output: {JSON.stringify(this.state.value)}</h4>
          </Col>
        </InputGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DateOfBirthInput;
```

Parent component

```
...
<InputGroup>
  <Col span={24}>
    <Field
      label="Date of Birth"
      name="userInfo.dateOfBirth"
      placeholder="Date of Birth"
      component={DateOfBirthInput}
     />
  </Col>
</InputGroup>
...
```

How do I get the pass the value from child component's state to parent component?

As per the documentation, I need to pass `value` and `onChange` event and it should work.
https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.5/docs/faq/customcomponent.md/

I guess I am missing something in the parent component.
Please help.

Comment: You can't pass the child's state to parent component like that. Generally, you hold state in the parent. Pass the `handleChange` handler to child, then pass the related value to the parent using this handler. Parent updates the state. Also, I don't know `lodash`, but if `_.get` does not create a new object do not use it. State is mutable and you should not change its value like that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @devserkan, it helped me point in the right direction. I got the component working my triggering input's onChange event in handleChange function.                                                                                                     
    const DateString:string = date.year+ '-' + date.month + '-' + date.day;
    this.props.input.onChange(DateString);
  }

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Got the component working. Here is the solution

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Col, Input } from 'antd';

const InputGroup = Input.Group;

class DateOfBirthInput extends React.Component<any, any> {
  public value:any = 'abc';

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value:{}
    };
    this.value = "DateSr";
    console.log(props);
  }

  public handleChange = (event: any) => {
    const date:any = _.get(this.state,"value");
    if(event.target.id === 'day'){
      date.day = event.target.value;
    }
    if(event.target.id === 'month'){
      date.month = event.target.value;
    }
    if(event.target.id === 'year'){
      date.year = event.target.value;
    }
    this.setState({
      value: date
    });
    const DateString:string = date.year+ '-' + date.month + '-' + date.day;
    this.props.input.onChange(DateString);
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="ant-form-item-label"><label title="Date of birth">Date of birth</label></div>
        <InputGroup>
          <Col span={4}>
            <Input
              placeholder="MM"
              name="legalInfo.dateOfBirth"
              id="month"
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </Col>
          <Col span={1}/>
          <Col span={4}>
            <Input
              placeholder="DD"
              name="legalInfo.dateOfBirth"
              id="day"
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </Col>
          <Col span={1}/>
          <Col span={5}>
            <Input
              placeholder="YYYY"
              name="legalInfo.dateOfBirth"
              id="year"
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <h4>Date of birth output: {JSON.stringify(this.state.value)}</h4>
          </Col>
        </InputGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DateOfBirthInput;
```

Hope it helps